# Magento - extending product.info.addtocart to add new "add to cart buttons"

Tags: magento

I would like to add a new add to cart button, much like paypal express checkout button.

I managed to plugin to the form via " product.info.extrahint " but the issue is, when you use this in catalog.xml, it puts your button above the "qty" and "addtocart" button's. What I want to do is add it to the end of the "product.info.addtocart" in catalog.xml

(from catalog.xml)

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.extra_buttons" as="extra_buttons" template="mycustomexpresscheckout/pay.phtml" />
```

Adding that makes the button appear in the right place, but this isn't how the paypal express button is done. for paypal express, the button is added to the "addtocart" block. Infact, if i remove that block, both my original add to cart and paypalexpress checkout buttons are gone.

Here's the original: http://www.bounceapp.com/86522

Here's my one with the altered`catalog.xml`: http://www.bounceapp.com/86523

Can anyone assist, or point me in the right direction?

Magento 1.6 - default template

Answer (score 1):

You can include block **product.info.extra_buttons** inside **product.info.addtocart** as

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml">
     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.extra_buttons" as="extra_buttons" template="mycustomexpresscheckout/pay.phtml" />
</block>
```

After that you need to  call the child block **(product.info.extra_buttons)** inside `addtocart.phtml` as `$this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons');`

Answer (score 0):

In your `local.xml`, under the `<catalog_product_view>` node just put this code and it should work:

```
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.extra_buttons" as="extra_buttons" template="mycustomexpresscheckout/pay.phtml" />
</reference>
```

For me it's working without adding `getChildHtml('extra_buttons')` in `addtocart.phtml`. Hope will work for you to...